# How can centering predictor variables reduce correlation between them?

Tags: correlation, inference, centering

In Statistical Rethinking by Richard McElreath on pg. 320 he states “centering predictors can aid in inference, by reducing correlations among parameters”.  For a linear equation with an interaction term.

What is this supposed to mean? Surely centering a variable will not change its correlation with another variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centering or scaling variables will not change their correlations, however it might change the linear model variance-covariance matrix, for ex.

```
> library(nlme)
> mod.lm0<-lm(distance~age*Sex,data=Orthodont)
> round(vcov(mod.lm0),2)

              (Intercept)   age SexFemale age:SexFemale
(Intercept)          2.01 -0.18     -2.01          0.18
age                 -0.18  0.02      0.18         -0.02
SexFemale           -2.01  0.18      4.92         -0.43
age:SexFemale        0.18 -0.02     -0.43          0.04

> mod.lm<-lm(distance~scale(age,scale=F)*Sex,data=Orthodont)
> round(vcov(mod.lm),2)

                                (Intercept) scale(age, scale = F) SexFemale scale(age, scale = F):SexFemale
(Intercept)                            0.08                  0.00     -0.08                            0.00
scale(age, scale = F)                  0.00                  0.02      0.00                           -0.02
SexFemale                             -0.08                  0.00      0.20                            0.00
scale(age, scale = F):SexFemale        0.00                 -0.02      0.00                            0.04
```

Comment: Is this matrix a variance-covariance matrix of etimated slopes?

Comment: `vcov` Returns the variance-covariance matrix of the main parameters of a fitted model object. That is, a matrix of the estimated covariances between the parameter estimates in the linear or non-linear predictor of the model. With row and column names corresponding to the parameter names given by the coef method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, if I get right, this is $\hat{\sigma}^2 (X'X)^{-1}$ where $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is the variance estimate of error. Centering has changed the design matrix so the variance covariance matrix has been affected, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how does this aid in inference?

Comment: Bigger variances -> bigger confidence intervals -> bigger p-values.